# Add the set of commands at the beginning of multipls files

Tags: linux, replace

I need to write a script for replacing a part of file with other. I am handling hundreds of files.

I have a list of commands to be added to a bunch of text files. But in the files I have a common commands at the beginning.

I simply want to replace to list of commands with my list of commands. Further information is given below.

**Original File**

```
%apj=E:\Work\Informatin\Regarding work\DND.apj
%mem=4GB
%nprocshared=2
#p oyu opsd qtnv/1-a(x) kglgg=uioewr

Application 

0 1
 X                 -3.66480600    0.10278400   -0.00655500
 Y                 -4.11487100    1.45621700   -0.05226200
 Z                 -5.10300200    1.90042600    0.83864800

 1 2 1.0 13 1.0 23 1.0
 2 3 1.5 4 1.5
 3 5 1.5 6 1.0
 4 7 1.5 8 1.0
```

**Characters I want to use to replace**

```
%apj=D:\Store\Data\Diff All\SMC.apj
%mem=800MB
%nprocshared=4
#p udf AMER hbvn/3-b(n) huggh=whea

Use

0 1
 X                 -3.66480600    0.10278400   -0.00655500
 Y                 -4.11487100    1.45621700   -0.05226200
 Z                 -5.10300200    1.90042600    0.83864800
```

After replacing with my list of commands, I also want to delete the characters that are found after a blank line i.e the following lines and retain the blank space.

```
1 2 1.0 13 1.0 23 1.0
2 3 1.5 4 1.5
3 5 1.5 6 1.0
4 7 1.5 8 1.0
```

Comment: Is it a paid task ?

Comment: Dear Jeff, It is not a paid task. I am a student working with computational science and I want to some kind of automation to make my job easier. I am new to this field and just starting to read basics . I am handling hundreds of such files , so it will be of help for me if someone can help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
sed '1,6d
7c%apj=D:\Store\Data\Diff All\SMC.apj\
%mem=800MB\
%nprocshared=4\
#p udf AMER hbvn/3-b(n) huggh=whea\
\
Use\

/^$/q' filename
```

Instead of replacing line by line, the first six lines are deleted (`1,6d`) and the seventh is replaced by the new header, inserted with the `c` command. Finally, processing is stopped at the next empty line.

If it gives the expected output, add option `-i` to perform the replacement directly on the file (GNU `sed`, adapt for BSD version).